# Setting up MySQL php artisan migrate - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

My task is to set up Laravel on my workstation and its already super complicated to me.

While setting up MySQL, I am getting the following error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = techpocket and table_name = migrations)

  at /Users/George/Sites/TechPocketnews/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /Users/George/Sites/TechPocketnews/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=techpocket", "root", "", [])
      /Users/George/Sites/TechPocketnews/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

when I am trying to run the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Below, is my mysql configuration from the app/config/database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Below, is my mysql configuration from the .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=techpocket
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I am a newbie with Laravel, be nice :)

Appreciate your help.

Sidenote: I am running PHP 7.1.7, MySQL 8.11 and Laravel 5.4

Comment: What happens if you remove the entire  `'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock')` line in database.php? If that works, I'll add an answer explaining _why_ that works. (but it's totally possible it doesn't)

Answer (score 2):

Had this same issue since I am using MAMP. I am on laravel 5.7 so my database.php has this line under the mysql directive:

> 'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),

The solution was to add the DB_SOCKET option which was missing on the environment file:

> DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score -1):

Add to app/Providers/AppServiceProviders.php:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
public function boot()
{
   Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

check with this. Hope it works.

**note**: still you got the error add

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

in .env file.